# Create quads from vertices

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces

I drew these vertices over a shape to copy it. I want to make faces out of these vertices. I am now manually clicking 4 vertices at a time and then fill them by pressing F.

Is there a faster way to do this?
[image]

Comment: use C to circle-select, then color a group of 4 at a time, so you don't have to click each vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as atomic's answer has suggested, placing vertices on a surface to copy it is perhaps not the most economical way  .. look up some sources on retopology in Blender.

However, since we're here,  one quicker way to do what you're doing is:

1. select all the vertices along a row, in order, from end to end.
2. hit <kbd>J</kbd> to create an edge loop along them
3. Bridge the edge loops you have. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> for the edge menu > 'Bridge Edge Loops')

Answer (score 2):

**Proportional Edit Saves Time**

---

[image]

The image above shows using a sphere as a starting point for mesh.

If its educational for you to draw vertices one by one then so be it.  No one can argue with that. Or can they?

The model does not appear to be an organic model or face model subject to high levels of inspection.   Also I am assuming a bowl shape with a drape is above.  Below a plane with moderate vertex density created in a few seconds with edit mode Subdivide.

If you choose to take a different approach I suggest you use

Proportional Editing.  That term can be searched here at BSE.

[image]

The image above shows edit mode proportional edit. The arrow shows the proportional edit button with tool tip.

There are many completed introductory videos on the famous video website that rhymes with noonoob. Video may serve you better. This writing is not a tutorial. You may also want to include shape keys. One could could also used a hemisphere as a starting mesh rather than a plane.  No artistry here. Just a technical suggestion.  Of course there are plenty of other ways to  achieve a similar mesh model.

Once you have practiced a few times with proportional edit you may recreate your model in 8 minutes or less.

Tutorial Link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrNVVHdKd3E

I suggest seeing many of these videos and especially one on Shrink Wrap or Cloth Simulation.